# How to display a snapping grid in JS on top of my HTML <img> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get a grid on which I want objects to snap on to, to display on top of my HTML page. The idea is to have busses follow along a certain route within my 'game'. This is all PHP / JS / CSS based.

I'm trying to use this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gho0Lv4b/ to display on top of this map https://oege.ie.hva.nl/~delawai/assets/images/Photos/map.jpg

I have tried using a canvas on top of the  tag with an rgba background of (0,0,0,0), but no dice.

```
///Grid

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', { selection: false });
var grid = 25;

// create grid

for (var i = 0; i < (2000 / grid); i++) {
  canvas.add(new fabric.Line([ i * grid, 0, i * grid, 2000], { stroke: '#ccc', selectable: false }));
  canvas.add(new fabric.Line([ 0, i * grid, 2000, i * grid], { stroke: '#ccc', selectable: false }))
}

// add objects

canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({ 
  left: 100, 
  top: 100, 
  width: 50, 
  height: 50, 
  fill: '#faa', 
  originX: 'left', 
  originY: 'top',
  centeredRotation: true
}));

canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({ 
  left: 300, 
  top: 300, 
  radius: 50, 
  fill: '#9f9', 
  originX: 'left', 
  originY: 'top',
  centeredRotation: true
}));

// snap to grid

canvas.on('object:moving', function(options) { 
  options.target.set({
    left: Math.round(options.target.left / grid) * grid,
    top: Math.round(options.target.top / grid) * grid
  });
});
```

And the HTML would be a simple canvas like such (I guess?)

```html
<canvas id="c" width="3016" height="2781" z-index="1"><img src="https://oege.ie.hva.nl/~delawai/assets/images/Photos/map.jpg" z-index="0"></canvas>
```

-- edit

Seems like the code provided below works. Now I am running in to the problem of embedding my images into the grid. I know to use

```
document.getElementById("...")
```

function. But I don't know where to add this function within the page.

For now I am trying to call the function like so:

```
// add custom objects
var bus = new Image();
  img.src = 'https://oege.ie.hva.nl/~delawai/assets/images/Photos/bus_geel.png';
document.getElementById(bus);
```

Any more help would be appreciated! I am really bad at JS. Sorry in advance

--
edit per 20/05

Seems like within a test.html this doesn't work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

<script src="kinetic.js"></script>


    <style>
        .container {
            position: relative;
        }

        canvas {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            border: 0px solid #ffffff;
        }

        img {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <canvas id="c" width="1920" height="1080"></canvas>
    <img height="1080" width="1920" src="https://oege.ie.hva.nl/~delawai/assets/images/Photos/map.jpg" z-index="0">
</div>

</body>

<script>


    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', { selection: false });
    var grid = 25;

    // create grid

    for (var i = 0; i < (600 / grid); i++) {
        canvas.add(new fabric.Line([ i * grid, 0, i * grid, 600], { stroke: '#ccc', selectable: false }));
        canvas.add(new fabric.Line([ 0, i * grid, 600, i * grid], { stroke: '#ccc', selectable: false }))
    }

    const url = 'https://oege.ie.hva.nl/~delawai/assets/images/Photos/bus_geel.png';

    fabric.Image.fromURL(url, (img) => {
//scale down the image but keeping the aspect ratio
        const width = 50;
        const height = 50;
        const widthFactor = width / img.width;
        const heightFactor = height/ img.height;
        const minFactor = Math.min(widthFactor, heightFactor);
        img.scale(minFactor);
        canvas.add(img)
    }, {
//here you can set the positioning
        left: 50,
        top: 100,
    });

    canvas.on('object:moving', function(options) {
        options.target.set({
            left: Math.round(options.target.left / grid) * grid,
            top: Math.round(options.target.top / grid) * grid
        });
    });
</script>
```

But it doesn't want to work. Tried externally calling the grid.js, embedding it like in this example. No dice. The map shows, but the grid does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add both the canvas and the img tags inside a div container.

Here is as fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ruaotqhx/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <canvas id="c" width="1920" height="1080"></canvas>
  <img height="1080" width="1920" src="https://oege.ie.hva.nl/~delawai/assets/images/Photos/map.jpg" z-index="0">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  position: relative;
}

canvas {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border: 0px solid #ffffff;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

To add img from an url to your grid you can simple do:

JS

```
const url = 'https://oege.ie.hva.nl/~delawai/assets/images/Photos/bus_geel.png'

fabric.Image.fromURL(url, (img) => {
//scale down the image but keeping the aspect ratio
    const width = 50;
    const height = 50;
    const widthFactor = width / img.width
    const heightFactor = height/ img.height
    const minFactor = Math.min(widthFactor, heightFactor)
    img.scale(minFactor)
    canvas.add(img)
}, {
//here you can set the positioning
  left: 50,
  top: 100,
});
```

Comment: Great! Thank you very much, it seems to work flawlessly. Didn't think I would get help this fast. I now also wonder, how do I get my own images to snap to this grid? Would I need to embed them in the javascript?

Comment: You mean snap them like the elements you created inside the canvas?

Comment: I just edited the answer  showing you how to get an img element from DOM and attaching it to your canvas, and the grid snapping will work the same way it does to the other canvas elements.

Comment: Thanks Ramon, but when I try to add [link](https://oege.ie.hva.nl/~delawai/assets/images/Photos/bus_geel.png) within the 'my-image' field, it doesnt turn up on the grid within the fiddle. I'm sorry you're having to answer to me so many times lol

Comment: Hey, no problem, I've updated it again, now showing an example of how to add a img to the canvas from a url. I hope it helps you!

Comment: Thanks a lot Ramon! Finally got it working thanks to your help. You're a godsend mate.

Comment: Hey Ramon, lastly, it doesn't seem to work when I embed it into the browser. I've added my test.html within the first post. Im sorry to bug you once more.

Comment: Is kinect.js script in the same directory of your test.html?

Comment: I noticed the fiddle had another .js which needed to be included. I have got it working. Thanks again!